# How can I filter based on date range with the dates per column in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I am attempting to make some reporting easier for a few teachers. These teachers need to keep track of attendance and the percentage of time that the students are receiving instruction. Unfortunately, they do not have a better system than Google Sheets at the moment.

Below is an example of what the attendance record looks like for all students.

- Column A is the student name
- Column B is the number of days present. This is determined with this formula: `=countif(D2:AAA2,"Y")`
- Column C is the percentage of days the student received instruction. Formula: `=B2/counta(D2:ZZ2)`
- Columns D through GX are school days. This is built using a config tab with first and last day, a list of holidays to exclude, the `WORKDAY.INTL` formula and finally a `TRANSPOSE` function on the sheet below to put these in columns.

[image: Example of spreadsheet showing attendance per date]

Now, the teachers are asking for the ability to show the days present (column B) and percentage (column C) based on a date range. I'd love to be able to use the same formulas above and set a range some how. I can't find a way to do this for dates in columns, though I have found a couple examples on how to do this if the dates were listed in rows (like this [example](https://www.statology.org/google-sheets-query-date-range/)).

How can I set up a dynamic (from two cells) upper and lower date range on the column B and C formulas?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/171770/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear cells `B2:C2` and put this formula in cell `B2`:

```
=let( 
  start, value("2023-08-16"), 
  end, value("2023-08-23"), 
  presence, filter(D2:2, isbetween(D$1:$1, start, end)), 
  daysPresent, counta(ifna(filter(presence, presence = "Y"))), 
  instructionPercentage, to_percent(daysPresent / counta(presence)), 
  hstack(daysPresent, instructionPercentage) 
)
```

To make the formula get its date range limits from two cells, replace the hard-coded dates in `start` and `end` with `$A$1` style references to those cells.